# Need help adding a section to TableViewController array

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to add a third section to the this `UITableViewController`. I've tried this :

```
        var listOfCauses:[[String]] = [
            ["Causes", "", ""],
            ["Cause 1" , "small descript", "links"],
            ["Cause 2", "small descript", "links"]
        ]
```

When I run the application table view the links subheading doesn't show. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance! Here is my full code for the `UITableViewController` below:

```
import UIKit

class CausesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        // I want to add the third section to this array
        var listOfCauses:[[String]] = [
            ["Causes", ""],
            ["Cause 1" , "small descript"],
            ["Cause 2", "small descript"]
        ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfCauses.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

               if cell == nil {
                   cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
               }

               cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
               cell!.textLabel!.text = listOfCauses[indexPath.row][0]
               cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .darkGray
               cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
               cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = listOfCauses[indexPath.row][1]

               return cell!
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update these methods

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return the number of sections
        return listOfCauses.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfCauses[section].count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

               if cell == nil {
                   cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
               }

               cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
               cell!.textLabel!.text = listOfCauses[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
               cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .darkGray
               cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
               cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = listOfCauses[indexPath.row][1]

               return cell!
    }
```